# Javascript - how does this button fires something?

Tags: javascript

Javascript is not my speciality.

I have a page that contains an image. This image, when clicked, fires an Ajax code, that shows a floating box. Analyzing the page code, I don't see how this button can fire the code.

The button is declared like this:

```
<div class="leaderboard-text">
  <span id="addon-add-language-button">
    <image class="ajaxListAddButtonEnabled" listId="localizationList"
           src="/itc/images/blue-add-language-button.png" />
    <image class="ajaxListAddButtonDisabled" listId="localizationList"
           style="display:none;" 
           src="/itc/images/blue-add-language-button-disabled.png" />
  </span>
</div>
```

just after this code, I see this var being declared:

```
<script language = "Javascript">
    var createList_localizationList = function() {
        var reorderEnabled = false;
        var preventLastRowDeletion = false;
        var searchEnabled = false;
        var list = new LCAjaxList();
        list.initialize():
    }
    document.observe("dom:loaded", createList_localizationList);
</script>
```

As far as I see, the image is firing somehow this javascript, but how can the button do that if there's no "onclick" or href reference tied to it? Where is the line that tells which method should run when the image is clicked?

What should I look on the code to get a clue how this button works?

What I need is to fire the method used by this button using javascript.

any clues?

================

after reading all that you guys have written, I have used Safari's Inspect Element and identified this listener attached to the object:

[image]

is this of any help? Now the question: how do I fire the method associated with this image from javascript? Thanks guys.

Comment: Search for the classes and IDs of it, and its surrounding DOM elements first.

Comment: Are you sure it's `<image` not `<img`?

Comment: yes, it appears to be image, not img. This was copied from the page.

Comment: To clarify, @DigitalRobot needs to find out, using Javascript, what events are attached to these images. He is writing automation and is trying to detect what events are tied to these items. He isn't trying to add click events to them. Rather he is trying to find out what events are already bound to the elements.

Comment: @aaronfrost: Is this your interpretation of the question? Or do you have more information than the others here? It is true the OP is not trying to attach click handlers, he wants to find existing listeners. I don't see anything about automation. If he wants to automate a click, every HTML object has a  click method that you can call. To me, the OP just can't figure out from the code, how the events are attached.

Comment: @DigitalRobot: Post the code for LCAjaxList

Comment: This is what he told me he needed to do.... so I added my comment so that everyone trying to help could further understand his question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My guess is that it's either one of the two statements

```
var list = new LCAjaxList();
list.initialize():
```

They seem really bad designed. A list object should take a DOM object to act upon. `LCAjaxList` probably hardcodes the element to bind to.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look at the new information. Thanks.

Comment: If you want to find out how the code is attaching the handlers, like I've said before, it's probably in the source code for LCAjaxList. However, if you want to simulate a click, the wrong solution is to find out the event handler that is attached and call it yourself. You should just emulate a click on the img, by calling `Element.click()` https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.click This way you don't have figure out what parameters to pass to the handler.

Answer (score 1):

When the DOM is completely loaded on the page it fires the event listener "createList_localizationList", so there is no need for a user to click on anything. You can add an event liseter to the button for onclick, instead of when the DOM loads with your button.

You could try this:

```
 $('ajaxListAddButtonEnabled').observe('click', createList_localizationList);
```

I am not sure if that class is used again, but maybe if you add an id to that element (id='someidname') to make sure you are not adding this to another element on the page.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look at the new information. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is .observe. That adds an event listener, so somewhere there may be

```
$('addon-add-language-button').observe('click', SomeFunction)
```

Event listeners are the preferred way to handle javascript events, rather than using an HTML onClick.

Comment: Good jQuery solution, but the question doesn't mention or show jQuery as a technology that they are using.

Comment: as far as I checked now, they appear to be using jQuery, but I don't see any reference like the one Aaron said. There are a lot of lines like that, but not to "addon-add-language-button". Probably they are targeting a div where the image ins on... I will continue searching

Comment: @aaronfrost - I have identified something like this ...observe('click', function (event)... now, how do I call this using javascript? :(

Comment: @DigitalRobot Look at my answer. That's a solution for you. Attaching the event listener instead of an anonymous listener (as the code was before).

Comment: @pqsk (... continues) discover what method runs when these images are clicked, know how to fire those methods from javascript, without clicking the image, so I can create automation.

Comment: I have updated the question. Please take a look at the new information. Thanks.

Comment: @DigitalRobot, given that explanation, I understand a little better what you are trying to do. I need to ask you... does the page have jQuery on it already? You can tell by typing 'jQuery' in the console and hit enter. If jQuery is undefined, then you don't. Otherwise you have it. A lot of sites are using jQuery now. If you site is new, it will most likely use jQuery. 

It is important to distinguish between jQuery and native Javascript because they bind events differently. Depending on jQuery/JS, you would accomplish your goals differently. Let me know.